# Java: Tool to control switching between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm

Does anybody know about a tool that allows the explicit switching of threads at certain points in the code?

I am testing Software Transactional Memory for my bachelor thesis and for these tests, I need specific execution orders of threads (e.g. thread 1 reads 2 variables, after that switch to thread 2 and write to a variable, etc.). The problem is, the software library implementing the STM prohibits normal java synchronizaton methods in the code, so I cannot use sychronized blocks, locks or semaphores.

I was hoping someone knows about a tool like Concurrit (https://code.google.com/archive/p/concurrit/), only for Java...

Comment: I don't believe such a thing exists

Comment: or could exist.

Comment: First, you would have to stop the preemptive switching that will happen at arbitrary points. You would need a custom JVM for that. Besides that, it seems you are not aware about the ordering issues that can arise independently of the thread scheduling. You would have to turn off all optimizations, perhaps even compilation in general and run everything interpreted only. Which raises questions about the relevance of the test results…

Comment: use jcstress for testing of concurrent code

Answer (score 0):

No such tool exists.  The only way you could achieve something like this would be to (drastically) modify the JVM itself, replacing the existing thread scheduling mechanisms.  That would be an impractically large project ... by itself.

Opinion: the Concurrit DSL is not designed to be a practical programming language, and adding the mechanisms that it provides to a practical programming language most likely would make it it non-performant.  Naturally, there is unlikely to be much enthusiasm for implementing such a tool for a performant<sup>1</sup> language such as Java.

---

<sup>1 - Relatively speaking.</sup>

Comment: It is not for pracitcal use. It is just to test some code for university. The runtime for that is not important, as the examples will be quite small.

Comment: Well, as I explained, it is *unlikely* that someone would go to the (considerable) effort of developing such a tool / environment for Java because it *would be* impractical.